# ALAsset - access thumbnail later

Tags: ios, alasset

I use `ALAssetsLibrary` to enumerate assets from the photo library but there is one problem. If I'm inside the block (the one for enumeration) I can access the thumbnail image without problem. However if I store the `ALAsset` in a collection and try to access the thumbnail image at some point later its 0x00000000.

Why this? Is there a better way to access individual images later?

My code works like this:

```
assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"bla bla bla ... problem");}];
```

with

```
void (^assetGroupEnumerator) (ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{

    if(group != nil)
    {
        // extract every asset from goup
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }

};
```

and

```
void (^assetEnumerator) (ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

[assets addObject:result];

}
```

Comment: Show your code. Particularly how you're storing the assets and how you are managing the assets library.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem being the (all to early) release of the `ALAssetsLibrary`. I should not give it up as long as I need the thumbnails and whatever else and simply keep its reference.